# Argument Controller is not a function, got undefined - two Angular apps in one page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I essentially have something like this

```js
(function(){
 'use strict';
 angular.module('app', []).controller('AppController', AppController);
 AppController.$inject = ['$scope'];
 function AppController($scope) {
  //controller stuff
 }
})();

(function(){
 'use strict';
 angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('app'), ['app']);
 });
})();
```

```html
<div id="app" ng-controller="AppController">

  <div id="doc" ng-controller="DocController">
    {{hello}}
  </div>

  <script>
    var App = angular.module('DocApp', []).controller('DocController', DocController);
    DocController.$inject = ['$scope'];

    function DocController($scope) {
      $scope.hello = "HELLO WORLD";
    }
    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('doc'), ['DocApp']);
  </script>
</div>
```

but am receiving the error `Argument 'DocController' is not a function, got undefined`

my initial thought is that it has something to do with the two different apps, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Angular parses the page, it will encounter directives as it parses down the DOM tree.  In your case, it will parse DocController after AppController.  As a result, it will expect that DocController is a registered module (within your current app scope) that it has access to.

However, you are not registering DocController until *afterwards* in a separate script tag, meaning that it not defined when Angular is parsing the page and, even if it were defined, it hasn't been injected into your app module.

The easiest way to fix this is to move the script up above your app entrance point but below your AngularJS inclusion reference so that it is parsed and added before AngularJS bootstraps your app and begins parsing the DOM and then inject it.

Since the app is really just another module, once it is included you need to reference it in your app module so that it is injected and available:

```
angular.module('app', ['DocApp']).controller('AppController', AppController);
```

Comment: I apologize. When converting the code from my work to SO, I forgot to change that. The typo doesn't exist in my code and I updated the OP respectively

Comment: @EmbattledSwag not a problem.  Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you start the `app` module **entire DOM beneath** `<div id="app" ...` is parsed.

This means that when `<div id="doc" ng-controller="DocController">` is encountered the `DocController` has to exists within **`app` module**. In your sample the `DocController` exists only in **`DocApp` module** hence the error.